# Project Euler #8 - what am I doing wrong? (c++)

Tags: c++

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now. The code below works for 4 digits (it matches with the answer they give) and it even works for 5 consecutive digits (which was what the problem previously asked for), but it doesn't seem to work for 13 consecutive digits.

Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int Char_To_String(char);

int main()
{
    /*****************************************************/
    /*********** PROJECT EULER: PROBLEM #8 ***************/
    /*****************************************************/

    fstream file("grid.txt", ios::in); // open file for reading

    if(!file)
    {
        cout << "FILE NOT OPENED!";
        return 0;
    }

    int row = 20;
    int column = 50;
    int num;
    char arr[row][column];
    int intarr[row][column];

    for(int i = 0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<column; j++)
        {

            file >> arr[i][j];
            intarr[i][j] = Char_To_String(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }


    long long prod = 1;
    long long int maxProd = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<column; j++)
        {
           if(j<=column-13)
           {
                int temp = j;
                for(int n = 1; n<=13; n++)
                {
                    prod *= intarr[i][temp];

                        temp++;

                }

                if(prod > maxProd)
                    maxProd = prod;

                prod = 1;

           }

        }
    }

    cout << "maxProd = " << fixed << maxProd << endl;
```

Comment: You're over complicating it by storing the number in a 2 dimensional array.  Even though it's shown as grid on the site, it's just asking about the number as a whole.

Comment: Oh. My. God. I can't believe THAT was where I was going wrong the whole time. Im so stupid. I see a grid, I automatically think 2D array, lol. Thanks so much man, it worked.